# blockUI getting removed in setInterval where where ajax call is made

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippet where an ajax call is made in every 5 sec interval to check if the response is true. The UI will be blocked till the response received is true and when the response is true the UI will be unblocked. I am using Jquery blockUI v1.0 plugin to block the UI:

```
$.fn.suspendResumeonConfirm=function(caseNumber,correlationId){ 
var contents=$('<table style="width:240px;"><tr><td align="center" style="padding: 5px;">Waiting for Response</td></tr><tr><td  align="center" style="padding: 5px;">'+
        '<div id="testProgress"  style="height:10px;background:#f1f1f1;"></div></td></tr><tr><td  align="center" style="padding: 5px;">'+
        '<label class="remainingTime">  </label> Seconds Remaining</td></tr></table>');
        contents.find('div#testProgress').progressbar("destroy").progressbar({value:0}).css("border","1px solid #e4e4e4");
        var progressUpdate=$("<div id='progressUpdate'></div>").append(contents);           
        var timeOut=0,
        response=false;         
        $("body").blockUI(true,{message:progressUpdate,css:{width:250}});
        var interval=setInterval(function() {               
            timeOut++;
            if(timeOut % 5==0){
                var param='entityNumber='+caseNumber+'&correlationId='+correlationId+'&entityType=Case&status=REQ';
                $(this).cAjax('POST','CheckRequestStatus.action',param,false,false,'','Error', true);
                response=strResponseText;
                //$(this).cAjax('POST', 'CheckRequestStatus.action',param,true,true,'serviceCallBack','Error', true,{timeOut:timeOut});
                $('#testProgress').progressbar("option", "value", (timeOut/serviceAlterationTimeout)*100);
                $("div#progressUpdate label.remainingTime").text((serviceAlterationTimeout-timeOut));
            }
            if(timeOut==60){
$('#testProgress').progressbar("option", "value", (timeOut/serviceAlterationTimeout)*100);
                $("div#progressUpdate label.remainingTime").text((serviceAlterationTimeout-timeOut));           
                $("body").blockUI(false);                   
                clearInterval(interval);
 }
        }
        , 1000);
};

$.fn.cAjax =  function(cType, cUrl, cData, cCache, cAsync, cFn, cAlert, cPrData,     functionArguments)
{
var self = $(this).eq(0),
    xhrObj = {};
try{
    strResponseText = "";
    xhrObj = $.ajax({
        type: cType,
        url: cUrl,
        data: cData,
        cache: cCache,
        async: cAsync,
        processData:cPrData? true : false,
        // ; Event will be called on Ajax SUCCESS
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if  ((typeof data).toUpperCase() == "OBJECT"){  
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
            }
                if(data.indexOf('Session Expired') != -1){
                    $(window.location).attr('href',  'Dashboard.action');
                }
                else if(data =="System error")
                {
                    var btnObject = {
                            "OK": function()   {$(this).dialog('close');}};
                      $(this).removeLoadingMsg().cDialog('customErrorDialog',sysErrorObj[0],sysErrorObj[1],false,true,null,null,btnObject,false,null,false,"slide","center");
                }
                else{
                    if(cFn && cFn != '')
                    {
                        if(typeof functionArguments ==   'boolean' || functionArguments)
                            self[cFn](data,   functionArguments);       //calling function by jquery Object notation    
                        else
                            self[cFn](data);
                    }
                    strResponseText = data;
                    return data;
                }
                return false;
    },

        // ; Event will be called on Ajax ERROR
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                var btnObject = {
                        "OK": function()  {$(this).dialog('close');}},errLabelCon = "";

                errLabelCon = $(this).errorCode(xhr.status);
                errLabelCon = errLabelCon.split(",");
                //abort handling. Callback function will receive   first argment as string "ABORT" and passed arguments if any
                if(ajaxOptions == "abort")
                {
                    if(cFn && cFn != '')
                    {
                        if(typeof functionArguments == 'boolean' || functionArguments)
                            self[cFn]("ABORT", functionArguments);      //calling function by jquery Object notation    
                        else
                            self[cFn]("ABORT");
                    }
                }
                else if(errLabelCon.length == 2)
                // replaced removeLoadingMsg with blockUI so that   current loading should be remove not all
                       $(this).blockUI(false).cDialog(null,errLabelCon[0],errLabelCon[1],false,true,null,null,btnObject,false,null,false,"slide","center");
    },

        // ; Event will be called on Request Complete
        complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
                //; alert("Complete:  "+strResponseText+"  "+textStatus+" "+XMLHttpRequest);
                if(strResponseText.indexOf('Session Expired') != -1){
                    $(window.location).attr('href', 'Dashboard.action');
                }
                if(strResponseText=="System error")
                {
                    var btnObject = {
                            "OK": function(){$(this).dialog('close');}};
                    $(this).removeLoadingMsg().cDialog('customErrorDialog',sysErrorObj[0],sysErrorObj[1],false,true,null,null,btnObject,false,null,false,"slide","center");
                }
    }
    });
    //store the XHR object so that it can be used while ajax in progress
    $(this).data("xhr", xhrObj);
}
catch(e){
    var btnObject = {
            "OK": function(){$(this).dialog('close');},
            "Click to Login": function(){$(this).dialog('close');$(window.location).attr('href', 'LogonFwdAction.action');}};
    var exception = sysErrorObj[1];

    exception += "<br />"+e;

    $(this).cDialog('customErrorDialog',sysErrorObj[0],exception,false,true,null,null,btnObject,false,null,false,"slide","center");
}
};
```

The problem is that after an ajax call is made in the setInterval the UI automatically gets unblocked for the next interval. But if I remove the ajax call in the setInterval the blockUI persists.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite see why the ui unblocks prematurely however I have had a go at refactoring and tidying the code and think the result is easier to follow.

My main objective was to avoid having to pass `cFn` and `functionArguments` to `cAjax()`. This is achieved by passing a `jQuery.Deferred` object instead, allowing `cFn` functionality to be executed in `suspendResumeonConfirm()`.

```
$.fn.suspendResumeonConfirm = function(caseNumber,correlationId) {
    var contents = $('<table style="width:240px;"><tr><td align="center" style="padding: 5px;">Waiting for Response</td></tr><tr><td align="center" style="padding: 5px;">'+
        '<div id="testProgress" style="height:10px;background:#f1f1f1;"></div></td></tr><tr><td align="center" style="padding: 5px;">' +
        '<label class="remainingTime">  </label> Seconds Remaining</td></tr></table>');
    contents.find('div#testProgress').progressbar("destroy").progressbar({value:0}).css("border", "1px solid #e4e4e4");
    var progressUpdate = $("<div id='progressUpdate'></div>").append(contents);
    var timeOut = 0,
        pollInterval = 5,//seconds
        $$ = {//cache of jQuery objects
            body: $("body"),
            testProgress: $('#testProgress'),
            remainingTime: $("div#progressUpdate label.remainingTime")
        };
    $$.body.blockUI(true, { message:progressUpdate, css:{width:250} });
    function unblockUI() {
        $$.body.blockUI(false);
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    var param = {'entityNumber':caseNumber, 'correlationId':correlationId, 'entityType':'Case', 'status':'REQ'};
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var xhr = $(this).data("xhr");//previous xhr object
        if(xhr) {//if there was a previous iteration
            if(xhr.abort) {
                xhr.abort();//abort
            }
            else if(xhr.reject) {
                xhr.reject();//or reject
            }
        }
        timeOut += pollInterval;
        var def = $.Deferred();
        var xhr = $(this).cAjax('POST', 'CheckRequestStatus.action', param, false, false, true, def);
        $(this).data("xhr", xhr);
        $.when(def).done(function(data) {
            //do other stuff here??
            if(data ...) {//test for a successful response
                unblockUI();
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeLoadingMsg();//??
            }
        }).fail(function(action) {
            switch(action) {
                case "abort":
                    $(this).whatever("ABORT", ...);
                break;
                case 'Session Expired':
                    window.location.href = 'Dashboard.action';
                break;
                case 'System error':
                    $(this).removeLoadingMsg();
                break;
            }
        });
        $$.testProgress.progressbar("option", "value", (timeOut/serviceAlterationTimeout)*100);
        $$.remainingTime.text((serviceAlterationTimeout-timeOut));
    }, pollInterval * 1000);
    setTimeout(unblockUI, serviceAlterationTimeout);//timeout
};

$.fn.cAjax = function(cType, cUrl, cData, cCache, cAsync, cPrData, def) {
    var xhrObj,
        btnObject = {
            "OK": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        };
    try {
        return $.ajax({
            type: cType,
            url: cUrl,
            data: cData,
            cache: cCache,
            async: cAsync,
            processData: cPrData ? true : false,
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if((typeof data).toUpperCase() == "OBJECT") {
                    data = JSON.stringify(data);
                }
                if(data.indexOf('Session Expired') != -1) {
                    def.reject('Session Expired');
                }
                else if(data == "System error") {
                    $(this).cDialog('customErrorDialog', sysErrorObj[0], sysErrorObj[1], false, true, null, null, btnObject, false, null, false, "slide", "center");
                    def.reject('System error');
                }
                else {
                    def.resolve(data);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                var errLabelCon = $(this).errorCode(xhr.status).split(",");
                if(textStatus !== "abort" && errLabelCon.length == 2) {
                    $(this).cDialog(null, errLabelCon[0], errLabelCon[1], false, true, null, null, btnObject, false, null, false, "slide", "center");
                }
                def.reject(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        var btnObject2 = $.extend(btnObject, {
            "Click to Login": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $(window.location).attr('href', 'LogonFwdAction.action');
            }
        });
        var exception = sysErrorObj[1] + "<br />" + e;
        $(this).cDialog('customErrorDialog', sysErrorObj[0], exception, false, true, null, null, btnObject2, false, null, false, "slide", "center");
        return $.Deferred().promise();//dummy promise instead of xhr
    }
};
```

*Tested only to check there are no parse errors*

Although the code should be structurally robust, it is incomplete in a couple of places so you will need to go through to finish it off and get it to do exactly what you want.